# Total memory for page tables & Number of pages (from the movie The Social Network)

Tags: cpu-architecture, virtual-memory, page-tables

After watching the movie *The Social Network (2010)*, I'm working on that Harvard sample question which seems to have inspired the scriptwriter. I just wanted to refresh my memory about Computer Architecture.

> A sample problem: Suppose we are given a computer with a 16-bit
> virtual addresses, and a page size of 256 bytes. The system uses
> one-level page tables, which start at address 0x0400. (The first few
> pages are reserved for hardware flags, etc. Maybe you wanted to have
> DMA on your 16-bit system, who knows?) Assume page table entries have
> eight status bits: 1 valid bit, 1 modify bit, 1 reference bit, and 5
> permissions bits (this is a very secure system).
> How many pages are there? How much memory do the page tables require?

Sadly, I find myself not fully confident about my own answer. I think the physical memory space is 2^16 - 2^10 (when you exclude the memory space up to 0x0400), and so the number of pages should be 252 (=(2^16 - 2^10) / 256). Given the size of each physical memory entry as big as two bytes (8 bits for PPN + 8 bits for page offset), the page table should take up 504 bytes (252 entries x 2 bytes).

Am I still missing something here?

Answer (score 2):

Given the surrounding text, I think "reserved" means not usable for regular user-space, i.e. reserved for MMIO addresses.  Not that software can't touch it at all.

So you'd want to be able to map *any* physical page address to a virtual address (so your OS can read/write those hardware flags).

So you'd actually want all 256 PTEs, instead of biasing your page-table indexing by subtracting 3 from the virtual page number.

But then yes, 2-byte PTE (page table entries) consisting of 8 flag bits and 8 page-frame (physical page) page-number bits, and you need 256 of them.  (The high 8 bits of a virtual address, i.e. virtual page number, can have 256 values).